# How to put a comment into HQL (Hibernate Query Language)?

Tags: database, nhibernate, comments

Is it possible to put comments into Hibernate Query Language?  If so, how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFAIK, HQL does not support comments.

Comment: I think I agree.  Does anyone have a definitive answer?

Comment: What kind of brain-dead language does not support comments in this century!? Unbelievable

Answer (score 23):

Make sure your session is configured with:

```
<property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

Then do:

```
Query query = ...;
query.setComment("Some comment here");
```

and you will see something like the following in your MySQL log file (if you're using MySQL):

```
5998 Query /* Some comment here */ select .....
```

Comment: +1 For the nice tip!  I wanted comments in the source but this is close :)

Comment: how to configure this in grails?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps your development, Hibernate Tools (Eclipse) supports double hyphens as single-line comments in their HQL editor. Helps me a lot. I've just tried the JPQL statement

```
SELECT pro --ro.id, cl.name, te.ordinalNbr, tt.code, se.startYear, pro.id, pcl.name, pte.ordinalNbr, ptt.code, pse.startYear
FROM Roster ro
  JOIN ro.season se
  JOIN ro.team te
  JOIN te.club cl
  JOIN te.teamType tt
  JOIN te.rosters pro
  JOIN pro.season pse
  JOIN pro.team pte
  JOIN pte.club pcl
  JOIN pte.teamType ptt
WHERE ro.id = 32
ORDER BY pse.startYear
```

and it returned the pro instances.

Also not quite to the point, but it might be useful nontheless.