# What is this double hyphen and how can it be used in HQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, comments, hql

While writing a `mysql` query we can use either `#` or a double hyphen `(--)` to comment a line. So we tried the same in `hql` but, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196975/how-to-put-a-comment-into-hql-hibernate-query-language) link here says that **HQL does not support comments**.

Well when we tried to write a query in `hql-editor` we tried it, so the line followed was having different color like this

```
--  fetch students for marks entry
select s,
       classHis.classes.id,
       cd.academicYear 
from Student s 
join s.studentPreviousClassesHistory classHis 
join classHis.classes.classSchemewises classSchemewise 
join classSchemewise.curriculumSchemeDuration cd
```

We thought it would be a comment, but the query didn't execute.

With the help of the answer by **@Kawu** from the above link we were able to comment a column to be fetched like `classHis.classes.id`, but if I comment it like this `--classHis.classes.id, commented by abcd` again it gives the same exception. The weird thing was even after we commented a column, its value was retrieved (ResultSet was having three columns for above query).

So what is the use of this double hyphen? Is it having any particular name?